# Error "Failed to construct URI for OData request with request path" SAP Java VDM withQueryParameter

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have create a CAP VDM in java with SAP SDK 3.29.1.
In event handler @On read, i would like to pass the input filters to the VDM.

Es.

```
@On(event = CdsService.EVENT_READ, entity = "XXXX")
public void readXXX(CdsReadEventContext context) throws ODataException {

final String filter = context.getParameterInfo().getQueryParameter("$filter");
final List<XXXXX> dati = new DefaultXXXService().getAllXXXX().select().withQueryParameter("$filter", filter).executeRequest(dest);

}
```

When run the query in the log i get the error:
"Failed to construct URI for OData request with request path ..."
"Illegal character in query at index 95. ...."

But the path and filter is right for the call, can you help me?

In the old version sdk i used:

```
FilterExpression filtriFrontEnd =FilterExpressionConverter.convertTo(queryRequest.getQueryExpression());

final List<XXXX> area = new DefaultXXXXService().getAllXXX().filter(new UncheckedFilterExpression<>(filtriFrontEnd)).select().execute(new ErpConfigContext("XXX"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly format your question better. It is difficult to read. Consider wrapping code samples in backticks.

Comment: Hi Stani, I think the stack trace would be helpful to investigate it further. I also agree with @Emdee that better formatting and fewer shortenings will help to get to the essence of your question much faster.

Comment: Yes, please add the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the formatting I hope it is clearer.

Comment: @StaniSorre Please add the stack trace as requested. It helps us nail down the root cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When run the query in the log i get the error: "Failed to construct URI for OData request with request path ..." "Illegal character in query at index 95. ...."

Can you check whether the following works for you..?

```java
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata.client.request.ODataUriFactory;

final String filter = context.getParameterInfo().getQueryParameter("$filter");
final String encodedFilter = ODataUriFactory.encodeQuery(filter);
final List<XXXXX> dati = new DefaultXXXService().getAllXXXX().select().withQueryParameter("$filter", encodedFilter ).executeRequest(dest);
```

Please let me know, as this could be an issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

The method contract of `withQueryParameter` which explicitly warns about this API usage:

```
Using this function to bypass fluent helper method calls can lead to unsupported response handling. There is no contract on the order or priority of parameters added to the query.
```

Instead please use the `filter` function directly. There should be an entity field for the postal code, the code should look similar to this:

```java
new DefaultXXXService()
    .getAllXXXX()
    .filter(Entity.POSTAL_CODE.eq("16100"))
```

If this is not feasible in your use case I suggest to build this filter expression manually as you did before and apply encoding to it as Alex pointed out in his answer.

Comment: That was an example. I could have many combinations of filters with or or and, how do I split them.

Comment: Isn't there another alternative of passing all filters together like the old version of the SDK?

Comment: Also because a priori I don't know what filter they pass me through

Comment: Okay that makes sense, in that case the answer from Alex is probably the way to go as of today. I'll still leave my answer here for other people to see as they may have different requirements.